# Game Either Runs Poorly or at Different Speeds

Tags: c++, physics, sdl2

I'm making a simple 2D shooter game using C++ and SDL2. For my main game loop, I used the code from the famous [Fix Your Timestep](https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/) article. The problem is that, because I'm using a fixed delta time, the game's objects move at different speeds depending on the hardware of the computer it is being played on. On more powerful PCs, the game runs very fast, and on weaker PCs, it runs slowly.

I was able to get around this problem by removing the `if (frameTime > .25) { frameTime = .25; }` statement, however this caused, paradoxically, the game to run poorly on computers with more powerful CPUs. I'm not limiting the FPS, and so when I run the game on a powerful PC, it starts off running at around 1500 FPS, but then the FPS quickly drops to unplayable levels, all while using up a significant percentage of the CPU power. On weaker PCs, however, the game runs just fine.

My question is, how do I balance these two issues so that the game runs at an acceptable framerate, while also making sure that the game objects move at the same speed, regardless of the hardware it is being played on? The game runs at a low resolution and uses very simple graphics, so it should be able to run smoothly even on weak PCs.

Comment: You might want to profile your game on weaker PCs to determine where is the bottleneck. You should also define what's your minimum specs machine, and test it there so that it runs smoothly there.

Comment: "The problem is that, because I'm using a fixed delta time, the game's objects move at different speeds depending on the hardware of the computer it is being played on." That is the opposite of what the linked article achieves. If you're experiencing an issue like this, you did not implement your fixed timestep correctly, and you should show us your code so we can help you debug it.

Answer (score 0):

You should limit the speed from above as well. This most likely this is the reason why it behaves so strangely on a fast PC, it's simply too fast.
Try to implement such a limitation. Let's start with delay ~30ms per one frame and see. Then I recommend to experiments with this value.

Perhaps later one you'd like to add some physics and so on. With unlimited FPS the physics may become unstable. Keep that in mind.

Comment: The physics in the article linked is fixed and not tied to the graphics framerate. So that, if implemented correctly, there could be unlimited fps. I agree that the render rate should be limited to at most the redresh rate of the monitor.